# How to use sql replace function in update function of the codeigniter?

Tags: sql, function, codeigniter, replace

I have tried below things to apply to replace SQL function into the update query.

```
ee()->db->where_in('entry_id', $entrie_ids);
$data['title'] = 'REPLACE(title, "'.$ss_find.'", "'.$ss_replace.'")';
ee()->db->update('channel_titles', $data);
```

But it takes replace as a string not getting as the replace SQL function

I want to get a solution by proper code ignitor function without direct running pure SQL query.

Can any have idea bout this?

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have got the solution.

```
    ee()->db->where_in('entry_id', $entrie_ids);
    $replace_function = 'REPLACE(title, "'.$ss_find.'", "'.$ss_replace.'")';
    ee()->db->set('title', $replace_function, FALSE); //
    ee()->db->update('channel_titles');
    $bob = ee()->db->last_query();
```

We should use the set function and pass the false value in the third parameter of the set function. This thing will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE.